# plotting a number of specific lines in python

Tags: python

In my plot the x-axis contains dates, but i want to limit it so that they can start from a certain date and not consider the first years of my data 
I have tried this:

```
plt.figure
f_linear=interp1d(datasurf.iloc[:,0],datasurf.iloc[:,1])
plt.plot(datasurf.iloc[:,0],datasurf.iloc[:,1], label='Surface level')
plt.xlim(pd.Timestamp('2016-01-01'), pd.Timestamp('2019-09-14'))
plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.ylabel('Lake level(m)')
plt.legend()
```

but I have this error:
Failed to convert value(s) to axis units: Timestamp('2016-01-01 00:00:00')

Can someone suggest me something else please

Answer (score 0):

You need to adjust the inputs a little.
change:

```
plt.xlim(pd.Timestamp('2016-01-01'), pd.Timestamp('2019-09-14'))
```

to

```
plt.xlim([pd.Timestamp('2016-01-01T12'), pd.Timestamp('2019-09-14T12')])
```

as shown [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.html)

also you can use datetime

```
ax.set_xlim([datetime.date(2018, 1, 26), datetime.date(2018, 2, 1)])
```

Comment: I am still getting the same error, can I try something like this:                                                `plt.xlim(pd.date_range(start='2016-01-01', end='2019-09-14'))`

Comment: There is still a problem of conversion, I have this error: Failed to convert value(s) to axis units: datetime.date(2018, 1, 26)

Answer (score 0):

```
fig= plt.figure ()
ax= fig.add_subplot (111)
plt.scatter(metadata['Date'], metadata['Offset'], label='Offset')
ax.set_xlim(pd.Timestamp('01/28/2016'), pd.Timestamp('12/09/2019'))
ax.set_title('Offset as a fucntion of time')
ax.set_xlabel('Time')
ax.set_ylabel ('Offset')
ax.legend (loc='lower right')
```